# How to make custom changes to a VSCode extension directly from the extensions folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

Good day. I have a third-party VSCode extension that's been throwing an error all day. In order to actually diagnose this, and then submit an issue on the parent GitHub repository, I've been poking around and trying to figure out where the error is being thrown from.

I have a decent idea where the error is originating from, but I'd like to add a `console.debug` statements to confirm this.

My question is this: I've made changes to the actual VSCode extension source code (installed within the VSCode extensions folder ), but VSCode is not picking up those changes. What do I do? Clean the cache or something, I'm not quite sure.

The source file is basically just a Ts-compiled-to-JS file, so still pretty easy to work with.

I've checked out the Developer Tools Console (Ctrl+Shift+I), but the error stack is not particularly helpful.

Comment: why don't you clone the extension repo and debug the extension as the developers do, or restart VSC after any change in the user-extension directory, if the extension is activated the source code is no longer looked at

Comment: I've been doing that only. However, with the extension debugger, everything is working absolutely fine. In production, however, something is getting royally screwed over. Hence, i need the console.debug statements from within the source code in the extensions folder

Comment: then package the extension to a vsix file and install this vsix file from the Extension bar top menu, make sure you inc the version number each modification